# How can I make the multi-line list from SQLite table in Discord on Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make bot to send values from SQLite table as a list. Here is table called Employees:

### emp_id || emp_name || emp_position

### emp_1 || Jane || emp_pos1

### emp_2 || Jake || emp_pos2

Here is the function for my command to show the emp list:

```py
@bot.command()
async def EmpTest(ctx):

    with conn:
        cursor.execute("SELECT emp_name, emp_position, emp_id FROM Employees")
        emp_list = cursor.fetchall()

    for j in range(0):
        column = []
        for i in range(0):
            column += emp_list
        column += "\n"
        emp_list += column
    for column in emp_list:
       for item in column:
           print(item, end=" ")
       print()
    await ctx.send(emp_list)
```

It works perfectly fine when it prints in console:

```
Jane emp_pos1 emp_1
Jake emp_pos2 emp_2
```

But that's what Discord gave output after `ctx.send(emp_list):`
`[('Jane', 'emp_pos1', emp_1), ('Jake', 'emp_pos2', emp_2)]`
How can I make it to be send in Discord like in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're getting a data from **SQLite**, you get a `tuple` type data. In this case, you get a list of tuples.

So at first, you need to get each one of the items of the list. You can do that with a `for loop`.

```
for emp_info in emp_list:
    print(emp_info)
```

Simply, you printed 2 employees' information.

Then, you should delete the parentheses. There are several ways to do that. I'll show you one of the ways to do it.

You can use `string.join()` function. You can do this:

```py
for emp_info in emp_list:
    print(', '.join(emp_info))
```

Then you can edit this to your code like this:

```
for emp_info in emp_list:
    await ctx.send(', '.join(emp_info))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I run it - it show me an error, so I changed 
[[ for emp_info in emp_list:
    await ctx.send(', '.join(emp_info)) ]]
 on: 
    [[ for emp_info in emp_list:
        await ctx.send(', '.join(map(str, emp_info))) ]] And it works fine.